# Reputation and Badge Difference

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, reputation, chat, badges

If you go on [my chat account](https://chat.stackexchange.com/users/334454/ds-secret) which is based on my [Stack Overflow account](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9201313/ds-secret), they have different reputation and amount of badges as shown below. Why is that? Is this only a problem on my account or on everyone's account?

**My Real Amount of Reputation and Badges**

[image: My real amount of reputation and badges]

**The Amount of Reputation and Badges on Chat**[image: Amount of Reputation and Badges on Chat]

Comment: Badges and reputation are (almost) completely orthogonal things. Also that might be because of caching data, and not all views of your profile are updated in realtime, synchronously.

Comment: "This number here doesn't match that number there" shouldiblamecaching.com

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's not your chat account on Stack Overflow chat. You can tell because the URL is: `https://chat.stackexchange.com/users/334454/ds-secret`. Stack Overflow chat's url is `chat.stackoverflow.com`.

There are three different chat servers. That link goes to your Stack Exchange chat account. That total includes the reputation and badges you've earned on all sites... ish.

It's not always perfectly exact... if I add up your top five sites, you have 231 reputation (120+78+21+6+6)... which is pretty close to 233.

For comparison, here's my chat accounts on all three servers:

- [Meta Stack Exchange](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/users/284336/catija): `https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/users/284336/catija` (I have 22.9K rep here)
- [Stack Overflow](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/4548692/catija): `https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/4548692/catija` (I have only 109 rep here)
- [Stack Exchange](https://chat.stackexchange.com/users/139041/catija): `https://chat.stackexchange.com/users/139041/catija` (I have over 100K here)